# How to reopen hibernate session after session was closed?

Tags: java, hibernate

Is there is any session/hibernate function to reconnect/reopen

LOG: SEVERE: No operations allowed after connection closed.

Comment: no, you just need to open a new session/connection

Comment: If you were to provide more context (when does this happen, what are the frameworks you're using, and so on), then someone might be able to help you solve your *real* problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  You should create/open a new `Session`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code example how to ensure the session is always valid. Line 2 must reassign back the session as `openSession` returns a new session. Just `session.getSessionFactory().openSession()` is not enough.

```
if (!session.isOpen()) {
        session = session.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
}
// operate your session 
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(clazz);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Hibernate Docs about Seesion](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/Session.html) says

The `lifecycle` of a `Session` is bounded by the beginning and end of a `logical transaction`. (Long transactions might span several database transactions.)

Once your `transaction committed`,`Session` wont available. You have to create a new one.

Comment: Session is not always connected with logical transaction, You as programmer have to decide how it's proggrammed